# There is no like/comment button in my Facebook Test user's posts. Why is that?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-like, webhooks, facebook-comments

I cannot see the like/comment button in my test user's feed and hence there is no option for the same. I have enabled `user_likes` permission, the app is in development mode. Any idea?

Comment: Looks like this is not available for test users in the UI. Use a real account that has been added to an app role for testing instead.

Comment: @misorude,  i added a developer but now i am not getting like data..

Comment: And did you send that account through the login flow, so that they can grant the necessary permission to your app?

Comment: yes i did. not even getting in graph api explorer

Comment: So debugging the access token confirms the permission is actually grated, yes?

Comment: yes. that's right. i have created a pos in my fb wall and tried liking the post. actually now the post have 1 like, which does not seems to come in the graph response.

Comment: Seeing the number of likes on your own posts has nothing to do with `user_likes` permission, that is for the _pages_ liked by the user only. _“which does not seems to come in the graph response”_ - what’s the exact request you are making?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/198172/discussion-between-devios-and-misorude).